# SELECT privilege for all tables on a particular schema

Tags: sql

I want to grant SELECT privilege to all tables in a particular schema say 'A' to the user user 'B'. i know how to do for individual table say GRANT SELECT ON A.table_name to B; Can anyone help me with the SQL for granting privilege to all tables at one shot ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for SQL Server, then:

```
GRANT select ON SCHEMA :: Schema_A
 to User_B
```

(That's assuming the schema is named "Schema_A", and the user--or Role--is "User_B")

Comment: i ran this got ORA-00942 table or view doesn't exist, So i altered the session still the same error

Comment: Sounds like you may be running this on Oracle, in which case different syntax would be required.